# What can we say about the colourings of some subset of vertices of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, conjectures

I will clarify the question by defining some straightforward concepts.

Let G = (V, E) be a simple graph with chromatic number $k$. We call a subset $V'\subset V$ fully chromatic if every proper k-colouring of G uses also $k$ distinct colors on $V'$. We say such a fully chromatic set is minimal, if every subset of $V'$ is not fully chromatic.

Now I conjecture that for every G=(V, E) and every minimally chromatic set $V'\subset V$, there exists some graph $G^* = (V^*, E^*) $ that has the same proper k-colourings on $V^*$ as all proper k-colourings of $G$ restricted to $V'$.

Furtermore, I conjecture that $G$ has $G^*$ as a minor

Comment: What do you mean with „same proper k-colorings“ when speaking about distinct graphs? Furthermore what makes you believe the conjecture? Do you have minimal examples?

Comment: Most minimal example would be some graph G that has a subset V' of k vertices that have k distinct in every proper coloring. Then the restriction of colourings on V' would be {red, blue, green}, {red, blue, green,} {blue, red etc. Then these are equal to all proper colourings of K_3. In this example it's not so interesting because it are just the permutations,  but if you draw a graph and find a minimal chromatic subset of more than k vertices, you'll probably understand why I think the conjecture is true.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1US9hMQu2Ve0qN8x8Q-O7iwvBSNsOng23/view?usp=sharing.   Here is an example of all colourings  of G (I omitted permutations) restricted to  a minimal fully chromatic set V'.  It's quite easy to see why these are equal to the colourings of G*. You might think my example is a bit easy and uncreative, but  I can't come up with a more interesting structure for a minimal fully chromatic set. Just adjecent vertices or vertices that must be always the same color as an adjective vertix